# Div go out of viewport (like the StackOverflow bar at the top)

Tags: css, html, viewport

You've probably seen the toolbar from StackOverflow (at the top of this page), how it hangs outside the viewport. Both of the edges hang off the page and so does the top. I have tried this so many times but can't find an answer. How would I make a div behave like this- in html, css, or javascript- can someone help me? (Position:fixed; is not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Have a look at this page with Firebug.

Comment: "hangs outside the viewport"? How would I know, its not visible outside the viewport… The viewport mostly is the browser-window.

Comment: why is `position:fixed` not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just a div, but you have to turn off the paddings in the body that is around:

```
<body>
   <div class="bar">test</div>
</body>

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}

.bar {
  padding:3px;
  background-color:#ff7200;  
}
```

a div automatically has a `width` of `100%`

a [live sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/VYkt6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the grey bar at the top of the page then it's simply a div styled with a grey background and a negative bottom margin:

```
#custom-header {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: -31px;
}
```